# Converting R function to Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(year = rep(1981,times = 730),day = 1:730, 
             temp = sample(25:41,730,replace = T),plant.date = 305, 
             germ.gdd = 20,veg.gdd = 250,rep.gdd = 600,rip.gdd = 800)
```

This data has year 1981 and day that goes from 1 to 730 i.e. after day 365, next year starts
`temp` is the daily temperature. `plant.date` is the day of the year when a crop is planted. After the 
After a crop is planted, it needs to accumulate certain heat units in order to reach different growth stages.
`germ.gdd`, `veg.gdd`, `rep.gdd` and `rip.gdd` are the thermal units of four growth stages 
(germination, vegetative, reproductive and ripening).

I have a R function that calculates the no. of days that it takes to reach all of these growth 
stages. Here it is:

```
  func.pheno <- function(tmp,p,tb,to,tc,g.gdd,v.gdd,r.gdd,ri.gdd){

  tm <- tmp[1:length(tmp) >= p] 

  fT <- ifelse(tm >= tb & tm <= to,(tm - tb)/(to - tb),
             ifelse(to <= tm & tm <= tc,(tc - tm)/(tc - to),0))

  Te <- tb + fT*(to - tb)
  thermal.units <- Te - tb

  day.stage1 <- which.max(cumsum(thermal.units) >= g.gdd) 
  day.stage2 <- which.max(cumsum(thermal.units) >= v.gdd)
  day.stage3 <- which.max(cumsum(thermal.units) >= r.gdd) 
  day.stage4 <- which.max(cumsum(thermal.units) >= ri.gdd) 
  day.stage4 <- ifelse(day.stage4 <= day.stage3, length(thermal.units),day.stage4) 
  list(day.stage1,day.stage2,day.stage3,day.stage4)
  }
```

Running the above function:

```
  tb <- 10
  to <- 31
  tc <- 40

  df <- df %>% group_by(year) %>% dplyr::summarise(pheno.dates = paste(func.pheno(tmp = temp, 
                                p = unique(plant.date), 
                                tb = tb, 
                                to = to, 
                                tc = tc, 
                                g.gdd = unique(germ.gdd), 
                                v.gdd = unique(veg.gdd), 
                                r.gdd = unique(rep.gdd), 
                                ri.gdd = unique(rip.gdd)), 
                               collapse=","))

   df <- df %>% tidyr::separate(pheno.dates, c("dgerm","dveg","drep","drip"))

   # A tibble: 1 x 5
   year dgerm dveg  drep  drip 
   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
     1  1981 2     19    46    62
```

My actual data has multiple years so in order to apply the above function I can do:

```
        df %>% group_by(year) %>% my function
```

I am trying to develop a Rcpp solution because I found it faster for some other function. 
I do not come from a background of C++ so this is what I have done.

```
  #include <Rcpp.h>
  using namespace Rcpp;

  // [[Rcpp::export]]

  List PhenoModel(NumericVector day,
                  NumericVector temp,
                  NumericVector plant_date, # I noticed . is not accepted 
                  double tb,
                  double to,
                  double tc,
                  double g_gdd,
                  double v_gdd,
                  double r_gdd,
                  double ri_gdd) {

    int n = day.length();
    NumericVector fT(n);
    NumericVector Te(n);
    NumericVector thermal_units(n);

  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){

  # this tries to achieve this tm <- tmp[1:length(tmp) >= p]    
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){

      if (day[i] < plant_date) {
      temp[i] = 0;
    } else {
      temp[i] = temp[i];
    } 

  if (temp[i] <= tb & temp[i] <= to) {

      fT[i] = (temp[i] - tb)/(to - tb);
      Te[i] <- tb + fT[i]*(to - tb);
      thermal_units[i] <- Te[i] - tb;

  } else if (to <= temp[i] & temp[i] <= tc) { 

      ft[i] = (tc - temp[i])/(tc - to);
      Te[i] <- tb + fT[i]*(to - tb);
      thermal_units[i] <- Te[i] - tb;

    } else {

    ft[i] = 0;
    Te[i] <- tb + fT[i]*(to - tb);
    thermal_units[i] <- Te[i] - tb;
    }
```

It is here I am not able to progress further. How do I accumulate the thermal units to find the no. of days it takes to reach each growth stage and then return this in  the data frame as my R function does

Comment: This is a pretty long-winded question (hardly a *minimal* example).  Are you just asking "how do I do `which.max(cumsum(x) >= y)` in C++?  BTW, your R function only seems to have fast vectorised functions in it, so the speedup from RCpp may not be as much as you hope.

Comment: I concur with @dww. I will point out one issue: _C++_ indices start at **0** _not_ **1**. Thus, the `for` loops should be: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`. (e.g. `int i = 1` -> `int i = 0`).

Comment: Well technically yes.. This is what I am looking for  `which.max(cumsum(x) >= y)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the first index that verifies `cumsum(x) >= thr`, you can use this Rcpp function:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector min_ind_which(const NumericVector& x, double thr) {

  double sum = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    sum += x[i];
    if (sum >= thr) return IntegerVector::create(i + 1);
  }

  return IntegerVector::create();
}
```